# Can HTML attributes have apostrophes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-parsing, html

Due to a number of reasons I have ended up with some code that has the need to store JSON serialized objects inside of HTML attribute tags.

I have however run into a problem where one of my json serialized objects contains an apostrophe and as a result seems to be breaking jQuery.

Basically this is the behaviour...

**Here is the table header definition.**

```
<table class='DraggableRowTable' RowData='{"AuthorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Created":"\/Date(1319429903223+1100)\/","EditorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Modified":"\/Date(1319429903223+1100)\/","AssignedToID":"7daef058-d84c-43f5-9db1-8011c59673ee","DetailedTaskID":"169ea939-7cb7-4599-9c2a-9e8ef4dee641","Duration":4.0000,"EndDate":"\/Date(1319497200000+1100)\/","ManualCalculation":false,"RoleID":"944f0ea3-4312-4f14-9d00-c968a647996a","Sequence":14,"StartDate":"\/Date(1319429872333+1100)\/","Status":0,"SubSequence":0,"Task":{"AuthorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Created":"\/Date(1319172394650+1100)\/","EditorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Modified":"\/Date(1319172394650+1100)\/","AssignedToID":"7daef058-d84c-43f5-9db1-8011c59673ee","Duration":4,"IsActive":true,"ProductID":"dad82b06-7d28-4255-bf02-f709eeed64cd","RoleID":"944f0ea3-4312-4f14-9d00-c968a647996a","Sequence":14,"TaskDescription":"es reviewer is to review the following fields and provide feedback to the writer if they' need fixing:\u000d\u000a*description\u000d\u000a*key learning objectives\u000d\u000a*educational value statements","TaskID":"6f577537-ce4a-46cd-9eb6-29bd5756ab26","TaskName":"educational soundness review"},"TaskID":"6f577537-ce4a-46cd-9eb6-29bd5756ab26","WorkOrder":{"AuthorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Created":"\/Date(1319429872333+1100)\/","EditorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Modified":"\/Date(1319429872333+1100)\/","IsActive":true,"Priority":1,"ProductID":"dad82b06-7d28-4255-bf02-f709eeed64cd","Qty":1,"StartDate":"\/Date(1319429872333+1100)\/","Status":0,"Subtitle":null,"WorkOrderDescription":null,"WorkOrderExternalID":43,"WorkOrderID":"66c40ff8-56e1-4009-89ab-989b0e25d120","WorkOrderName":"Work order #43"},"WorkOrderID":"66c40ff8-56e1-4009-89ab-989b0e25d120"}'>
```

**And here is the code.**

```
var Data = $(GridRow).find(".DraggableRowTable").attr("RowData");
//Data = "{"AuthorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Created":"\/Date(1319429903223+1100)\/","EditorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Modified":"\/Date(1319429903223+1100)\/","AssignedToID":"7daef058-d84c-43f5-9db1-8011c59673ee","DetailedTaskID":"169ea939-7cb7-4599-9c2a-9e8ef4dee641","Duration":4.0000,"EndDate":"\/Date(1319497200000+1100)\/","ManualCalculation":false,"RoleID":"944f0ea3-4312-4f14-9d00-c968a647996a","Sequence":14,"StartDate":"\/Date(1319429872333+1100)\/","Status":0,"SubSequence":0,"Task":{"AuthorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Created":"\/Date(1319172394650+1100)\/","EditorID":"652c90e4-ffef-49c5-9217-0ff39a461011","Modified":"\/Date(1319172394650+1100)\/","AssignedToID":"7daef058-d84c-43f5-9db1-8011c59673ee","Duration":4,"IsActive":true,"ProductID":"dad82b06-7d28-4255-bf02-f709eeed64cd","RoleID":"944f0ea3-4312-4f14-9d00-c968a647996a","Sequence":14,"TaskDescription":"es reviewer is to review the following fields and provide feedback to the writer if they" //As you can see, it all breaks here...
```

So I guess Im wondering, firstly is it valid to have apostrophes in HTML attributes (IE: Does the HTML standard support this) and secondly (depending on the answer to the first) should jQuery be capable of returning this attribute correctly?

Comment: Wow, so wrong on so many levels.  I'm just speechless.

Comment: I hate comments like this. Rather then just point out something is wrong perhaps you would like to actually forward something constructive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say which version of HTML so I'll assume [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#attributes)

> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have any string value, including the empty string. Except where explicitly stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such attributes.

Your issue is you haven't encoded the apostrophy. You probably need to change occurrences of `'` to `&apos;`. You really should HTML encode the whole string.

Comment: I accept your criticism that the JSON should be encoded but if the standard allows for apostrophes (and your paragraph suggest that it does) doesn't this imply a bug in the jQuery implementation?

Comment: You have the whole tag attribute in single quotes; an embedded single quote has to be escaped somehow, and that's how you do it in HTML, by using an entity. Alternatively, you could have the attribute value in double quotes, and entity-escape all the double quotes instead, I suppose.